# HTTP call error to shopify when sending array in json request

Tags: go, httprequest, shopify-api

This is an http post response to create a new shopify blog.

```
blog := Blog{
        Title:           fileNameWithoutExtSliceNotation(doc.Name()),
        Template_suffix: "hit_parader_issue_template",
        Metafields: []BlogMeta{
            {
                Key:       "filter_tag_list",
                Value:     "Popular",
                Type:      "single_line_text_field",
                Namespace: "global",
            },
        },
    }

        blogJSON, err := json.Marshal(blog)
        blogReq, err := http.NewRequest("POST", newBlogQuery, bytes.NewBuffer(blogJSON))
        blogReq.Header.Add("X-Shopify-Access-Token", TOKEN)
        blogReq.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")

resp1, err := client.Do(blogReq)
```

my structs are like below

```
type Blog struct {
    Title           string `json:"title"`
    Template_suffix string `json:"template_suffix"`
    Metafields      []BlogMeta
}

type BlogMeta struct {
    Key       string
    Value     string
    Type      string
    Namespace string
}
```

im getting an error saying

{"errors":{"blog":"Required parameter missing or invalid"}}

These are my blow metafield definitions.

[image]

I have all the necessary fields listed in the following api call. Please help.

Im using below API

https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2022-10/resources/blog#post-blogs

NOTE: the API documentation says that I need to present a array for the metafields. But I think my code is correct. IS there something im missing? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looking at the API docs it seems to me that the blogJSON should be nested in a root object, i.e. it should be `{"blog": {"title": ...,}}`, but instead you're sending `{"title": ...,}`... If that's the case that would also explain the error message.

Comment: Hi @mkopriva. Thank you for your answer. Could you write down the blog Json array as a answer so I get this right?. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the API docs it seems that the blog JSON object should be nested in a root object, i.e. it should be `{"blog": {"title": ...,}}` rather than `{"title": ...,}`. If that's the case then that would also explain the error message.

To fix that you can do something like this:

```golang
blog := &Blog{
    // ...
}
data, err := json.Marshal(map[string]any{"blog": blog})
if err != nil {
    return err
}

r, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewReader(data))
if err != nil {
    return err
}
r.Header.Add("X-Shopify-Access-Token", TOKEN)
r.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
resp, err := client.Do(r)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
// ...
```

Comment: Hey @mkopriva.. The blog does get created but my initial issue was the metafields. they are not getting updated.